# Categorising a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've written a function that takes a number and returns a value depending on where that number lies on a pre-defined scale. That's probably a little confusing so I've put the code below and added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QqDz/) (although you might be better off in the dev console).

```
var getSize = function(number){
        var sizes = {
            100 : 'url_t',
            240 : 'url_s',
            320 : 'url_n',
            500 : 'url_m',
            640 : 'url_z',
            800 : 'url_c',
            1024 : 'url_l',
        },
        result = sizes[100];

    for (var size in sizes){
        if(number < size){
            result = sizes[size];
            break;
        }
        result = sizes[1024];
    }
    return result;
};
getSize(10) // returns url_t
getSize(130) // returns url_s
getSize(2000) // returns url_l
getSize(600) // returns url_z
```

It works and it's fairly performant, it's just a bit icky. I've tried to come up with a better solution but it just feels ickier. Is there anything I'm missing that would make this a bit nicer? I was playing about with putting the sizes in an array so they're a little more JSON-ish, but then I got lost.

Comment: I would not trust `for in` to be always properly sorted.

Comment: I agree, that's one of the reasons I was looking at putting it in an array. Whilst the above code does work, it's certainly not right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might not need to loop through an object, and a simple `switch` statement would suffice.

```
function getSize(number) {
    switch (true) {
        case number < 100: return "url_t";
        case number < 240: return "url_s";
        case number < 320: return "url_n";
        case number < 500: return "url_m";
        case number < 640: return "url_z";
        case number < 800: return "url_c";
        default:           return "url_l";
    }
}
```

As a side note, I've seem people use `switch (true)` before when they want to use some logic in their `case`'s instead of just hard coded values. Kind of a nice alternative to an `if-else` construct, and would probably perform better than looping over an object using a `for-in` loop.

You could still keep the sizes in an object:

```
var sizes = {
    100 : 'url_t',
    240 : 'url_s',
    320 : 'url_n',
    500 : 'url_m',
    640 : 'url_z',
    800 : 'url_c',
    1024 : 'url_l'
};

function getSize(number) {
    switch (true) {
        case number < 100: return sizes[100];
        case number < 240: return sizes[240];
        case number < 320: return sizes[320];
        case number < 500: return sizes[500];
        case number < 640: return sizes[640];
        case number < 800: return sizes[800];
        default:           return sizes[1024];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** A problem arises if you need to change the `sizes` for your application. That's why I'm leaning towards the first function, which just a switch statement and hard coded values.

Comment: In this simple example, the first is much more clear. However, if `sizes` were localized or loaded from some external source, then the second example would necessarily be the only option.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of switch statements. I generally stay away from them but this is almost a textbook case for them. Thanks Greg.

The only issue would be if the sizes were to change, or get passed in dynamically. They don't in this case though so it's all good.

Answer (score 6):

- Your `for..in` construct should have an `Object.hasOwnProperty` check in the extremely unlikely event that somebody decides to abuse prototypes (and on `Object`, no less!).
- Your indentation is a little inconsistent.
- You assign to the `result` variable excessively.
- Some values are hard-coded, but they shouldn't be. At the very least, move them into a constant instead of leaving them as magic numbers.

You could try something like the following:

```
var getSize = function(number) {
    var MAX_SIZE = 1024;

    var result;
    var sizes = {
        100: 't',
        240: 's',
        320: 'n',
        500: 'm',
        640: 'z',
        800: 'c',
        1024: 'l'
    };

    for (var size in sizes) {
        if (sizes.hasOwnProperty(size)) {
            if (number < size) {
                result = sizes[size];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return "url_" + (result || sizes[MAX_SIZE]);
}
```

Incidentally, is it intentional that `getSize(100)` will return `url_s` instead of `url_t`? If not, just change the `<` above to a `<=`.

---

**Revision**. Better yet, we can use `Object.keys()`. This has the advantage of being entirely unreliant on magic numbers; we can instead just change our `sizeMap` object as needed. Furthermore, this deals with @megawac's concern about the undefined enumeration of `for...in`.

```
var getSize = function(number) {
    var result;
    var sizeMap = {
        100: 't',
        240: 's',
        320: 'n',
        500: 'm',
        640: 'z',
        800: 'c',
        1024: 'l'
    };

    var sizes = Object.keys(sizeMap).sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        if (number < sizes[i]) {
            result = sizeMap[sizes[i]];
            break;
        }
    }
    return "url_" + (result || sizeMap[sizes[sizes.length - 1]]);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `result || sizeMap[sizes[sizes.length - 1]]` you can set `result = sizeMap[..]` before the if and return result

Answer (score 4):

Alright first thing **[the order that an engine enumerates object properties is not guaranteed](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164)!!!** Its pretty consistent but there are engine bugs and you shouldn't rely on the behaviour.

That said, this is how I would write your `getSize`. You can use `Object.keys(sizes)` to create the ranges list but again - order isn't gaurenteed. You could sort it I suppose?

```
var getSize = (function() {
    var sizes = {
        100 : 'url_t',
        240 : 'url_s',
        320 : 'url_n',
        500 : 'url_m',
        640 : 'url_z',
        800 : 'url_c',
        1024 : 'url_l',
    };
    // Note you can do Object.key(sizes); to create this list
    var ranges = [100, 240, 320, 500, 640, 800, 1024];

    return function(number) {
        for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; i++) {
            var key = ranges[i];
            if (number < key) {
                return sizes[key];
            }
        }
        // otherwise return the largest size
        return sizes[key];
    };
})();
```

It may be overkill but I also created the `sizes` and `ranges` object once

Comment: +1 for undefined enumeration order, was the first thing that jumped out at me (and the other answers seem to have missed it)

Comment: Spot on with the enumeration order. I was made aware of this when I was writing it but I couldn't think of a nice way around it.

Declaring the ranges is a good way around it but wouldn't the enumeration order issue still crop up if I created it with `Object.key(sizes)`?

Comment: @SamBeckham it depends on what environments you want to support. If you take a look at the chrome ticket theres a lot of talk about standardizing the order, in which case it will no longer be an issue. AFAIK all evergreen browsers will iterate numerical props in numeric order but some legacy will iterate in the order added

Comment: I would advise against relying on a feature which is explicitly undefined

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a variation on [Greg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/47364/greg-burghardt)'s excellent answer, but I would invert the sizes map to eliminate magic numbers:

```
var sizes = {
    url_t : 100,
    url_s : 240,
    url_n : 320,
    url_m : 500,
    url_z : 640,
    url_c : 800,
    url_l : 1024
};

function getSize(number) {
    switch (true) {
        case number < sizes.url_t: return 'url_t';
        case number < sizes.url_s: return 'url_s';
        case number < sizes.url_n: return 'url_n';
        case number < sizes.url_m: return 'url_m';
        case number < sizes.url_z: return 'url_z';
        case number < sizes.url_c: return 'url_c';
        default:           return 'url_l';
    }
}
```

Or, instead of the `switch`, to avoid the repetition of its `case` lines:

```
var names = ['url_t', 'url_s', 'url_n', 'url_m', 'url_z', 'url_c', 'url_l'];

function getSize(number) {
    for (var i in names) {
        var name = names[i];
        if (number < sizes[name]) {
            return name;
        }
    }
    return names[names.length - 1];
}
```

And another thing, keep in mind that a `,` right before the closing `}` is incorrect JavaScript and may not work in all browsers and environments:

```
// incorrect:
var sizes = { 1024 : 'url_l', }

// correct:
var sizes = { 1024 : 'url_l' }
```

Comment: Yeah, I always forget about that trailing comma. It's JSHint's favourite thing to catch me out on.

I prefer the switch without the sizes map to be honest. It seems like I'm basically repeating the same map inside the switch statement anyway. Thanks for all the help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I won't use the [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) structure.

It's loops thorught the properties of the object and also the properties of his prototype.

If that's your only choice you have to use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for every size you check to avoid posible errors.

I would use something like:

```
var sizes = {
 values: [100,240,320,500,640,800,1024],
 names: ['url_t', 'url_s', 'url_n', 'url_m', 'url_z', 'url_c', 'url_l']
},
```

and then the usual for loop.

Comment: I actually think `for..in` is completely valid here. It makes more sense than having to update two arrays...

Comment: I just feel more comfortable using arrays to save data, and objects for complex structures, but yeah, the two arrays solution will probably end wrong

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that about `for in`. I'm curious though, how could any properties be added to the sizes object in this case?